# How to GetProperties of an object that is List<T>

Tags: c#, properties, system.reflection

I need to get all properties of a class that have an element that is a list of other class and you don't know how is that class. I need to get the properties including those belonging to the second class.

```
class ClassOne { 
 public int i {get;set;} 
 public string str {get;set;}
};

class ClassTwo {
 public string b {get;set;}
 public List<One> somelist {get;set;}
};

ClassOne ele = new ClassOne();
ele.i = 1;
ele.str = "a";

ClassTwo two = new ClassTwo();
two.b = "b";
two.somelist = new List<ClassOne>();
two.somelist.Add(ele);
```

I need to get the properties names and values of somelist.

I would like to get an answer like:
property: "somelist"
subproperty:"i" value:1
subproperty: "str" value: "a"

Comment: Can you please [edit] the post to complete the example - as of now it is quite unclear what you want to *see* as result of " including properties of two.somelist" (it is quite unlikely you looking for `two.somelist.Count`...)

Comment: Just as Alex said your question is a bit unclear, but have you tried using inheritance? Maybe you should make the class inherit the properties of the other class using inheritance

Comment: you speak about properties and your classes have only fields....

Comment: I edit my question to clarify more